# Complex variable creation and usage in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xml?>
    <cars>
      <car model="Focus" manufacturer="Ford" year="2000"/>
      <car model="Golf" manufacturer="Volkswagen" year="1999"/>
      <car model="Camry" manufacturer="Toyota" year="1999"/>
      <car model="Civic" manufacturer="Honda" year="2000"/>
      <car model="Prizm" manufacturer="Chevrolet" year="2000"/>
    </cars>
```

I tried to apply the following XSLT:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="html" version="1.0"/>

<xsl:variable name="bgcolor">
 <body>#cccccc</body>
 <table>#ddddd</table>
 <row>#eeeeee</row>
 <altrow>#ffffff</altrow>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/">
 <html>
 <body bgcolor="{$bgcolor/body}">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </body>
 </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cars">
 <table bgcolor="{$bgcolor/table}" width="75%">
  <xsl:for-each select="car">
   <tr>
    <xsl:attribute name="bgcolor">
     <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="position() mod 2 = 0">
       <xsl:value-of select="$bgcolor/altrow"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="position() mod 2 = 1">
       <xsl:value-of select="$bgcolor/row"/>
      </xsl:when>
     </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:call-template name="car"/>
   </tr>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="car">
 <td><xsl:value-of select="@model"/></td>
 <td><xsl:value-of select="@manufacturer"/></td>
 <td><xsl:value-of select="@year"/></td>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

After applying the XSLT to XML I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
    <html>
    <body bgcolor="#cccccc">
    <table bgcolor="#cccccc" width="75%">
    <tr bgcolor="#cccccc">
      <td>Focus</td> 
      <td>Ford</td> 
      <td>2000</td> 
      </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#cccccc">
      <td>Golf</td> 
      <td>Volkswagen</td> 
      <td>1999</td> 
      </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#cccccc">
      <td>Camry</td> 
      <td>Toyota</td> 
      <td>1999</td> 
      </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#cccccc">
      <td>Civic</td> 
      <td>Honda</td> 
      <td>2000</td> 
      </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#cccccc">
      <td>Prizm</td> 
      <td>Chevrolet</td> 
      <td>2000</td> 
      </tr>
      </table>
      </body>
      </html>
```

What I need to get is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
    <html>
    <body bgcolor="#cccccc">
    <table bgcolor="#ddddd" width="75%">
    <tr bgcolor="#eeeeee">
      <td>Focus</td> 
      <td>Ford</td> 
      <td>2000</td> 
      </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#ffffff">
      <td>Golf</td> 
      <td>Volkswagen</td> 
      <td>1999</td> 
      </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#eeeeee">
      <td>Camry</td> 
      <td>Toyota</td> 
      <td>1999</td> 
      </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#ffffff">
      <td>Civic</td> 
      <td>Honda</td> 
      <td>2000</td> 
      </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#eeeeee">
      <td>Prizm</td> 
      <td>Chevrolet</td> 
      <td>2000</td> 
      </tr>
      </table>
      </body>
      </html>
```

It seems like the "complex" variable **$bgcolor** is using only the first value **#cccccc**. How can I change the code so that it uses the appropriate values on the selected elements? And I need to keep this **$bgcolor** variable as it is. Thank you!

Comment: The value of the variable is a single node, the document node of the temporary tree, could you try with: `<xsl:variable name="bgcolor"><colors><body>#cccccc</body><table>#ddddd</table><row>#eeeeee</row><altrow>#ffffff</altrow></colors></xsl:variable>` and select colors with: `$bgcolor/colors/body` etc.?

Comment: Which XSLT processor exactly is that? With (most) XSLT 1.0 processors the variable is a result tree fragment and any attempt like `{$bgcolor/body}` should result in an error that you have to convert it to a node-set first.

Comment: What do you mean by *"I need to keep this $bgcolor variable as it is"*? Who is forcing you to keep suboptimal code? The simple solution is to define a separate variable for each constant. Even simpler solution is to use those constants directly, since each one of them is only used once. If you want to use your redundant and overcomplicated structure, you must convert it a node-set first - if your processor allows such action. Every major XSLT 1.0 processor supports some `node-set()` extension function, but - as already noted - every major XSLT 1.0 processor will throw an error with your code.

Answer (score 1):

Using Saxon, I get an error because HTML version 1.0 is not supported. When I correct the `xsl:output` declaration, I get the output you are expecting.

With a conformant XSLT 1.0 processor I would expect an error because you are using a result-tree-fragment as a node-set, as Martin Honnen explains.

I can't think of any explanation for the output you say you are getting: I think it's a problem particular to your XSLT processor.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I think this is a particularly good approach, but if you want, you can get your stylesheet to recognize your variable as a node-set by treating it as a literal element instead of a variable. This is an alternative to using an extension function which your processor may or may not support:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:variable name="bgcolor">
    <body>#cccccc</body>
    <table>#ddddd</table>
    <row>#eeeeee</row>
    <altrow>#ffffff</altrow>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="bgcolors" select="document('')/xsl:stylesheet/xsl:variable[@name='bgcolor']" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body bgcolor="{$bgcolors/body}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cars">
    <table bgcolor="{$bgcolors/table}" width="75%">
        <xsl:for-each select="car">
            <tr>
                <xsl:attribute name="bgcolor">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="position() mod 2 = 1">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$bgcolors/row"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$bgcolors/altrow"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@model"/>
                </td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="@manufacturer"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@year"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

OTOH, your setup may not allow using the `document()` function to perform an internal lookup, so...

---

P.S. There is no HTML version 1.0. That too will throw an error with some processors.